# Using Javascript, how do I target 3 variables and apply Math.random() to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a code here using Javascript only (without having anything in the HTML body) so that everytime I refresh it generates random numbers that add up.

I have already tried using Math.random() and innerHTML but I believe I am using it in the wrong place. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<body>
    <div id="mathProblem">
        <!-- leave this div empty!-->
    </div>
<script>
    let myDiv = document.getElementById("mathProblem");
    var x;
    var y;
    var z;
    x = Math.random();
    y = Math.random();
    z = x + y
    myDiv.innerHTML = "she made"+ x "cookies but ate " + y, "she has" + z "cookies left";
    document.getElementById("mathProblem").innerHTML = z;
</script>
```

Finally, what I am basically trying to achieve is that every time I refresh, the X and Y variables are different and they add up to Z, hence resulting in a word problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's just some typos in the innerHTML declaration.

```
    myDiv.innerHTML = "she made"+ x + "cookies but ate " + y +  "she has" + z +"cookies left";
```

Make sure you're concatenating the string right.

You can also use string interpolation which would look like this:

```
myDiv.innerHTML = `she made ${x} cookies but ate ${y} she has ${z} cookies left`;
```

notice the back-ticks `` instead of double quotes `""`

So:

```
<body>
  <div id="mathProblem"><!-- leave this div empty!--></div>
  <script>
    const myDiv = document.getElementById("mathProblem");
    const x = Math.random();
    const y = Math.random();
    const z = x + y;
    myDiv.innerHTML = `she made ${x} cookies but ate ${y} she has ${z} cookies left`;
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues. First is that your javascript isn't completing as expected because of some missing plusses. The next is that you're assigning to the `innerHTML` twice. Finally, I imagine you're attempting to do integer math and express a logically correct sentence.

Give [this explanation of Random](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp) a read and check out the differences between your code (with syntactic corrections) and my code at [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbus6dky/). You can play around with the JS there if you want to try new things. What it boils down to is this change:

```
let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
let z = x + y;
document.getElementById("mathProblem").innerHTML = `she made ${z} cookies but ate ${y} she has ${x} cookies left`;
```

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't know that I was writing the x,y,z variables wrong as I'm still new to Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

> Math.random() does not provide cryptographically secure random
>   numbers. Do not use them for anything related to security. Use the Web
>   Crypto API instead, and more precisely the
>   window.crypto.getRandomValues() method.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

```js
genRandomNumbers = function getRandomNumbers() {
  var array = new Uint32Array(2);
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
 
  var randText = document.getElementById("myRandText");
  var resultText = document.getElementById("result");
  
  randText.innerHTML = "The random numbers are: "
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    randText.innerHTML += array[i] + " ";
  }
  resultText.innerHTML = array[0] + array[1];
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto -->

<p id="myRandText">The random numbers are: </p>
<p id="result">
Result:
</p>
<button type="button" onClick='genRandomNumbers()'>Generate 2 random numbers and add</button>
```

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/181580/why-is-math-random-not-designed-to-be-cryptographically-secure